# Как извлечь HTML ответ из iframe, где страница формируется Ajax-ом?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно извлечь ответ из айфрейма, внутри которого страница исполняется на аяксе, результат на аяксе выводится. Не получилось достать этот ответ, пробовал на jQuery contents(), JS. Возвращается пустота, которая между тегами айфрейма, а сам ответ со страницы, который аякс - не исполняется, он не возвращается через айфрейм.

Есть страница c поиском туроператора
http://anextour.com.ua/search?TOWNFROMINC=155&STATEINC=11&CHECKIN_BEG=20181226&CHECKIN_END=20181226&NIGHTS_FROM=3&NIGHTS_TILL=28&STARS=&MEAL=&ADULT=2&CHILD=0

вся огромная форма поиска формируется аяксом + результат поиска тоже аяксом.

Эта форма на вышеприведенную страницу вставляется iframe-ом, вот сам адрес формы, с айфрейма достал
http://online3.anextour.com.ua/default.php?page=search_tour&DOLOAD=1&FREIGHT=&TOWNFROMINC=155&STATEINC=11&CHECKIN_BEG=20181226&CHECKIN_END=20181226&NIGHTS_FROM=3&NIGHTS_TILL=28&STARS=&MEAL=&ADULT=2&CHILD=0

Я делаю расширение для гугл хром, которое должно иметь доступ к ответу формы поиска на странице http://anextour.com.ua/search?TOWNFROMINC=155&STATEINC=11&CHECKIN_BEG=20181226&CHECKIN_END=20181226&NIGHTS_FROM=3&NIGHTS_TILL=28&STARS=&MEAL=&ADULT=2&CHILD=0

пробовал так:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
```

и так:

```
var $iframe = $("iframe#frameID");
    $iframe.on('load', function(){
        var iFrameDOM = $iframe.contents();
        iFrameDOM.find("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    });
```

и так:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <title>iframehide</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var f=$('#foo')
            f.load(function(){ 
                f.contents().find('div').hide(); 
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="foo" src="iframehide-frame.html" /></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

и так:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = x.contentDocument;
```

Все способы возвращают пустоту, ни один из способов не извлекает отработанный айфреймом HTML, подскажите пожалуйста, как получить именно отработанный айфреймом аяксовый ответ ?

Comment: Ваш код не дожидается завершения `ajax`-а внутри `iframe`-а

Comment: Iframe для того и существует. Его контент вытащить нельзя. Никак.

Comment: Чтобы общатся с данными внутри iFrame нужно использовать [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), по другому никак.

Answer (score 0):

В расширении хрома можно использовать `Сontent Scripts` для запуска своего скрипта на странице с последующим извлечением содержимого страницы

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

или `webRequest` для перехвата трафика на более низком уровне

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest